# Laravel model relation - change to mutator, without chaning anything in cotrollers

Tags: php, laravel, orm, relation

I have 2 tables, estimates and models.
There's a 1-to-1 relation between the two. 
I want to move model names from the models table to the estimates table. That will be done with a script that I will have to write myself.
The way this database was set up was wrong, for many reasons I don't need to specify here.
The models table has only 2 columns - id and name.

I access this relation in a lot of controllers, and views all over my app :

```
$estimate->model_info->name
```

So I would keep both the models table (with no records) and the Model.php model, keep the old code in the controllers and views, but the new code of accessing model names would be just :

```
$estimate->name
```

In the Estimate.php model I have this relation :

```
public function model_info() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Model', 'id', 'model_id');
}
```

How can I just change this relation into a mutator, so the old way of accessing model names and the new way would work at the same time?
I've tried the **withDefault()** callback method with no luck, it returns an empty value :

```
public function model_info() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Model', 'id', 'model_id')
                ->withDefault([
                    'name' => $this->attribute->name
                ]);
}
```

Do I have to update my code in all controllers and views or if there's an easier way to do this?